# C++ Linux string.h invalid read reported in valgrind

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind, string.h

The Linux program below builds a path by adding some strings to a filesystem path:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
int main(int, char**) {

    //
    std::cout << "Application STARTING\n";

    //
    fs::path path;

    // Add to path
    path /= "/media";
    path /= "aaa";
    path /= "bbb";
    // path /= "ccc";

    //
    std::cout << path.c_str() << std::endl;

    //
    std::cout << "Application STOPPED\n";

}
```

If I run this file in valgrind, this is the output:

```
Application STARTING
/media/aaa/bbb
Application STOPPED
```

If I uncomment the line that adds "ccc" to the path, compile and run again in valgrind, I get this:

```
Application STARTING
==2231== Invalid read of size 1
==2231==    at 0x4860214: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so)
==2231==  Address 0x4d25c17 is 0 bytes after a block of size 31 alloc'd
==2231==    at 0x4848744: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:282)
==2231==    by 0x4A79CBB: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==2231==
/media/aaa/bbb/ccc
Application STOPPED
```

I am compiling with these settings:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -I/usr/include/alsa  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -DTMTP_DEBUG -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/tmtp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /media/ssd/projects/tmtp/code/main.cpp
```

Is this a valgrind error?  Am I using the fs::path correctly?

_ UPDATE _

I have reduced to the minimum compiler settings:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++   -g -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/tmtp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /media/ssd/projects/tmtp/code/main.cpp
```

I am compiling in C++17 because this allows me to use the non-experimental version of filesystem.

Bad memory read is still reported.

_ ANOTHER UPDATE _

I can create the invalid read error without using filesystem.  The code below also reports an invalid read.  There are two lines marked in the code, commenting out either removes the invalid read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class CPath
{

    public:
            inline const char* c_str() const { return m_strPath.c_str(); }
            inline void operator/=(const char* psz) { append(psz); }

    public:
        void append(const char* psz)
        {

            //
            m_strPath += '/'; // <--- REMOVE TO PREVENT INVALID READ
            m_strPath.append(psz);

        }

    private:
        std::string m_strPath;

};


int main(int, char**) {

    //
    std::cout << "Application STARTING\n";

    //
    CPath path;
    path /= "media";
    path /= "aaa";
    path /= "bbb";
    path /= "ccc"; // <--- REMOVE TO PREVENT INVALID READ

    //
    std::cout << path.c_str() << std::endl;

    //
    std::cout << "Application STOPPED\n";

}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code that's shown here. Therefore, the problem must be with the code that's obviously not shown here, and was left out. That's where the bug is. Unfortunately, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out the problem with code that's not even shown. Just because the program crashes here doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere, but it doesn't immediately crash and the programs runs for a little bit before finally crashing at a random line of code.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the standard C++ library you're using.

Comment: Try to add a line like this:
char* p = new char[8];
I suspect you will get an error.

Comment: KonstantinL: You are correct.  I now have two invalid reads and I don't know what caused either.

Comment: @Richard, it seems you are compiling embedded software with forbidden dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: KonstantinL: Thanks for the reply.  How do I remedy this?  I am building on a Raspberry Pi using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.

Comment: @Richard, do not use dynamic memory allocation directly and/or indirectly. Also if you are new to embedded software development I could recommend to start with plain C instead of C++ and purposefully learn about all the restrictions implied by embedded system/programming.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as obviously incorrect.